# Python sqlite parameter extension problem

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table with three columns, `cell`, `trx` and `type`.
This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
db.execute("SELECT cell,trx FROM tchdrop").fetchall()
```

It gives the correct output.

However when I try `a = ("cell", "trx")` and then

```
db.execute("SELECT ?,? FROM tchdrop", t).fetchall()
```

the output is `[(u'cell', u'trx'), (u'cell', u'trx')]` (which is wrong)

I'm doing this to figure out how to extract columns dynamically which is a part of a bigger problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place holder (?) of python DB-API (like sqlite3) don't support columns names to be passed, so you have to use python string formatting like this:

```
a = ("cell", "trx")

query = "SELECT {0},{1} FROM tchdrop".format(*a)
db.execute(query)
```

EDIT:

if you don't know the length of the columns that you want to pass , you can do something like this:

```
a = ("cell", "trx", "foo", "bar")
a = ", ".join(a)

query = "SELECT {0} FROM tchdrop".format(a)
# OUTPUT : 'SELECT cell, trx, foo, bar FROM tchdrop'
db.execute(query)
```

Comment: then, what do I do if I don't know the length of a?

Answer (score 0):

The library replaces the specified values `("cell", "trx")` with their quoted SQL equivalent, so what you get is `SELECT "cell", "trx" FROM tchdrop`. The result is correct.

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with the `?` syntax. Instead, do string replacement yourself. You can check column names with regular expressions (like `^[a-zA-Z_]$`) for more security.

For example:

```
columns = ",".join(("cell", "trx"))
db.execute("SELECT %s FROM tchdrop" % columns).fetchall()
```